# Jpos Xml incoming message format

Tags: java, c#, xml, iso8583, jpos

I sent the message to server and got a response not in a correct form as stated below
**This is how I send the message**

```
{<isomsg>
<!-- org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager[C:/isoxml/Procenneiso87binary.xml] -->
<field id="0" value="0800"/>
<field id="7" value="1108154836"/>
<field id="11" value="162757"/>
<field id="12" value="094017"/>
<field id="13" value="1109"/>
<field id="70" value="301"/>
</isomsg>
```

**This is the response from the server**

```
 <isomsg direction="incoming">
 <!--org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager[C:/isoxml/Procenneiso87binary.xml] -->
 <header>3038313082</header>
 <field id="0" value="8&#0;&#0;&#2;"/>
 <field id="30" value="&#0;&#0;&#0;110815"/>
</isomsg>
}
```

I sent an echo message.
This is how I send the message

```
            byte[] tpduHeader = new byte[10];
            tpduHeader = ISOUtil.str2bcd("6000000000", true);
            GenericPackager packager = new GenericPackager(utlOperation.GetConfigStr("IsoXML_Path", "N/A"));
            BaseChannel channel = new NACChannel(packager, tpduHeader);
            channel.setHost(hostName, portNum);
            channel.connect();

            ISOMsg isoMsg = new ISOMsg();
            isoMsg.setPackager(packager);
            isoMsg.setMTI("0800");
            //isoMsg.set(45, keyValue["Field_2"]+"^nidhipathak    ^030912345);
            isoMsg.set(7, "1108154836");
            isoMsg.set(11, "162757");
            isoMsg.set(12, "094017");
            isoMsg.set(13, "1109");
            isoMsg.set(70, "301");
            pLogger.INF("Iso8583 Message Format input - ClientData: " + isoMsg);
            ByteArrayOutputStream str = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(str);
            org.jpos.util.Logger logger = new org.jpos.util.Logger();
            logger.addListener(new SimpleLogListener(ps));
            //dump the data
            isoMsg.dump(ps, ""); 
            // Get and print the output result
            byte[] RequestedData = isoMsg.pack();
            System.Console.WriteLine(ISOUtil.hexdump(RequestedData));
            System.Console.WriteLine("**" + Hex.encodeHexString(RequestedData) + "**");
            pLogger.INF("HEX Iso8583 Message Format input - ClientData: " + "**" + Hex.encodeHexString(RequestedData) + "**");

            int len = RequestedData.Length;
            byte[] buf = new byte[(len + 2)];
            buf[0] = ((byte)((len >> 8 & 255)));
            buf[1] = ((byte)((len & 255)));
            Array.Copy(RequestedData, 0, buf, 2, len);

            channel.send(buf);

            ISOMsg responseIsoMsg = new ISOMsg();
            responseIsoMsg.setPackager(packager);
            responseIsoMsg = channel.receive();
            byte[] responseData = responseIsoMsg.pack();
            responseIsoMsg.dump(ps, "");
            System.Console.WriteLine(responseIsoMsg);
            channel.getSocket().close();
            channel.disconnect();
```

Actually I got a good response in 320 message type however I can not read the incoming message correctly.

this is my xml file

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        <!DOCTYPE isopackager SYSTEM "http://jpos.org/dtd/generic-packager-1.0.dtd" PUBLIC "-//jPOS/jPOS Generic Packager DTD 1.0//EN">

        <!-- field 52 (PIN DATA): IFA_BINARY replaced by IFB_BINARY field 127 (RESERVED PRIVATE USE): IFA_LLLBINARY replaced by IFA_LLLLLLBINARY See: http://groups-beta.google.com/group/jpos-users/browse_thread/thread/e60807e917c8c170/e29a681592d63a2b#e29a681592d63a2b -->

        -<isopackager>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="MESSAGE TYPE INDICATOR" length="4" id="0"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_BITMAP" name="BIT MAP" length="16" id="1"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM" name="PAN - PRIMARY ACCOUNT NUMBER" length="19" id="2"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="PROCESSING CODE" length="6" id="3"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="AMOUNT, TRANSACTION" length="12" id="4"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="AMOUNT, SETTLEMENT" length="12" id="5"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="AMOUNT, CARDHOLDER BILLING" length="12" id="6"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="TRANSMISSION DATE AND TIME" length="10" id="7"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="AMOUNT, CARDHOLDER BILLING FEE" length="8" id="8"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="CONVERSION RATE, SETTLEMENT" length="8" id="9"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="CONVERSION RATE, CARDHOLDER BILLING" length="8" id="10"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="SYSTEM TRACE AUDIT NUMBER" length="6" id="11"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="TIME, LOCAL TRANSACTION" length="6" id="12"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="DATE, LOCAL TRANSACTION" length="4" id="13"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="DATE, EXPIRATION" length="4" id="14"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="DATE, SETTLEMENT" length="4" id="15"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="DATE, CONVERSION" length="4" id="16"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="DATE, CAPTURE" length="4" id="17"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="MERCHANTS TYPE" length="4" id="18"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="ACQUIRING INSTITUTION COUNTRY CODE" length="3" id="19"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="PAN EXTENDED COUNTRY CODE" length="3" id="20"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="FORWARDING INSTITUTION COUNTRY CODE" length="3" id="21"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="POINT OF SERVICE ENTRY MODE" length="3" id="22"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="CARD SEQUENCE NUMBER" length="3" id="23"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="NETWORK INTERNATIONAL IDENTIFIEER" length="3" id="24"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="POINT OF SERVICE CONDITION CODE" length="2" id="25"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="POINT OF SERVICE PIN CAPTURE CODE" length="2" id="26"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="AUTHORIZATION IDENTIFICATION RESP LEN" length="1" id="27"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_AMOUNT" name="AMOUNT, TRANSACTION FEE" length="9" id="28"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_AMOUNT" name="AMOUNT, SETTLEMENT FEE" length="9" id="29"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_AMOUNT" name="AMOUNT, TRANSACTION PROCESSING FEE" length="9" id="30"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_AMOUNT" name="AMOUNT, SETTLEMENT PROCESSING FEE" length="9" id="31"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM" name="ACQUIRING INSTITUTION IDENT CODE" length="11" id="32"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM" name="FORWARDING INSTITUTION IDENT CODE" length="11" id="33"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" name="PAN EXTENDED" length="28" id="34"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM" name="TRACK 2 DATA" length="37" id="35"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="TRACK 3 DATA" length="104" id="36"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="RETRIEVAL REFERENCE NUMBER" length="12" id="37"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="AUTHORIZATION IDENTIFICATION RESPONSE" length="6" id="38"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="RESPONSE CODE" length="2" id="39"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="SERVICE RESTRICTION CODE" length="3" id="40"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="CARD ACCEPTOR TERMINAL IDENTIFICACION" length="8" id="41"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="CARD ACCEPTOR IDENTIFICATION CODE" length="15" id="42"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="CARD ACCEPTOR NAME/LOCATION" length="40" id="43"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" name="ADITIONAL RESPONSE DATA" length="25" id="44"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" name="TRACK 1 DATA" length="76" id="45"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="ADITIONAL DATA - ISO" length="999" id="46"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="ADITIONAL DATA - NATIONAL" length="999" id="47"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="ADITIONAL DATA - PRIVATE" length="999" id="48"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="CURRENCY CODE, TRANSACTION" length="3" id="49"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="CURRENCY CODE, SETTLEMENT" length="3" id="50"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="CURRENCY CODE, CARDHOLDER BILLING" length="3" id="51"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_BINARY" name="PIN DATA" length="8" id="52"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_BINARY " name="SECURITY RELATED CONTROL INFORMATION" length="48" id="53"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="ADDITIONAL AMOUNTS" length="120" id="54"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED ISO" length="999" id="55"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED ISO" length="999" id="56"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED NATIONAL" length="999" id="57"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED NATIONAL" length="999" id="58"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED NATIONAL" length="999" id="59"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED PRIVATE" length="999" id="60"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED PRIVATE" length="999" id="61"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED PRIVATE" length="999" id="62"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED PRIVATE" length="999" id="63"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BINARY" name="MESSAGE AUTHENTICATION CODE FIELD" length="8" id="64"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BINARY" name="BITMAP, EXTENDED" length="8" id="65"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="SETTLEMENT CODE" length="1" id="66"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="EXTENDED PAYMENT CODE" length="2" id="67"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="RECEIVING INSTITUTION COUNTRY CODE" length="3" id="68"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="SETTLEMENT INSTITUTION COUNTRY CODE" length="3" id="69"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="NETWORK MANAGEMENT INFORMATION CODE" length="3" id="70"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="MESSAGE NUMBER" length="4" id="71"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="MESSAGE NUMBER LAST" length="4" id="72"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="DATE ACTION" length="6" id="73"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="CREDITS NUMBER" length="10" id="74"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="CREDITS REVERSAL NUMBER" length="10" id="75"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="DEBITS NUMBER" length="10" id="76"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="DEBITS REVERSAL NUMBER" length="10" id="77"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="TRANSFER NUMBER" length="10" id="78"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="TRANSFER REVERSAL NUMBER" length="10" id="79"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="INQUIRIES NUMBER" length="10" id="80"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="AUTHORIZATION NUMBER" length="10" id="81"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="CREDITS, PROCESSING FEE AMOUNT" length="12" id="82"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="CREDITS, TRANSACTION FEE AMOUNT" length="12" id="83"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="DEBITS, PROCESSING FEE AMOUNT" length="12" id="84"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="DEBITS, TRANSACTION FEE AMOUNT" length="12" id="85"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="CREDITS, AMOUNT" length="16" id="86"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="CREDITS, REVERSAL AMOUNT" length="16" id="87"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="DEBITS, AMOUNT" length="16" id="88"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="DEBITS, REVERSAL AMOUNT" length="16" id="89"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="ORIGINAL DATA ELEMENTS" length="42" id="90"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="FILE UPDATE CODE" length="1" id="91"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="FILE SECURITY CODE" length="2" id="92"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="RESPONSE INDICATOR" length="5" id="93"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="SERVICE INDICATOR" length="7" id="94"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="REPLACEMENT AMOUNTS" length="42" id="95"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BINARY" name="MESSAGE SECURITY CODE" length="8" id="96"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_AMOUNT" name="AMOUNT, NET SETTLEMENT" length="17" id="97"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="PAYEE" length="25" id="98"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM" name="SETTLEMENT INSTITUTION IDENT CODE" length="11" id="99"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM" name="RECEIVING INSTITUTION IDENT CODE" length="11" id="100"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" name="FILE NAME" length="17" id="101"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" name="ACCOUNT IDENTIFICATION 1" length="28" id="102"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" name="ACCOUNT IDENTIFICATION 2" length="28" id="103"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="TRANSACTION DESCRIPTION" length="100" id="104"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED ISO USE" length="999" id="105"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED ISO USE" length="999" id="106"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED ISO USE" length="999" id="107"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED ISO USE" length="999" id="108"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED ISO USE" length="999" id="109"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED ISO USE" length="999" id="110"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED ISO USE" length="999" id="111"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED NATIONAL USE" length="999" id="112"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED NATIONAL USE" length="999" id="113"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED NATIONAL USE" length="999" id="114"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED NATIONAL USE" length="999" id="115"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED NATIONAL USE" length="999" id="116"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED NATIONAL USE" length="999" id="117"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED NATIONAL USE" length="999" id="118"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED NATIONAL USE" length="999" id="119"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED PRIVATE USE" length="999" id="120"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED PRIVATE USE" length="999" id="121"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED PRIVATE USE" length="999" id="122"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED PRIVATE USE" length="999" id="123"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED PRIVATE USE" length="999" id="124"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED PRIVATE USE" length="999" id="125"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RESERVED PRIVATE USE" length="999" id="126"/>


        -<isofieldpackager class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLLLLBINARY" name="RESERVED PRIVATE USE" length="999999" id="127" packager="org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericSubFieldPackager">

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="PLACEHOLDER" length="0" id="0"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_BITMAP" name="BITMAP" length="8" id="1"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" name="SWITCH KEY" length="32" id="2"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="ROUTING INFORMATION" length="48" id="3"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="POS DATA" length="22" id="4"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="SERVICE STATION DATA" length="73" id="5"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="AUTHORIZATION PROFILE" length="2" id="6"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" name="CHECK DATA" length="50" id="7"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="RETENTION DATA" length="128" id="8"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="ADDITIONAL NODE DATA" length="255" id="9"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="CVV2" length="3" id="10"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" name="ORIGINAL KEY" length="32" id="11"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" name="TERMINAL OWNDER" length="25" id="12"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="POS GEOGRAPHIC DATA" length="17" id="13"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="SPONSOR BANK" length="8" id="14"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" name="AVS REQUEST" length="29" id="15"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="AVS RESPONSE" length="1" id="16"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" name="CARDHOLDER INFORMATION" length="50" id="17"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" name="VALIDATION DATA" length="50" id="18"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="BANK DETAILS" length="45" id="19"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" name="AUTHORIZER DATE SETTLEMENT" length="8" id="20"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" name="RECORD IDENTIFICATION" length="12" id="21"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLLLCHAR" name="STRUCTURED DATA" length="99999" id="22"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" name="PAYEE NAME AND ADDRESS" length="253" id="23"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" name="PAYER ACCOUNT INFORMATION" length="28" id="24"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLLCHAR" name="ICC DATA" length="8000" id="25"/>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" name="ORIGINAL NODE" length="20" id="26"/>

        </isofieldpackager>

        <isofield class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" name="MAC 2" length="999" id="128"/>

        </isopackager>
```

Comment: Did you even read the answers provided to you in the jpos users mailing list?

Comment: Do you even read my question as ıt is not about sending the message, ıt is about incoming message. And not everyone follows the jpos group. If someone answers in jpos, I will share it here. If you are not going to contribute in anway, there is no need to text a message as yours. It is redundant.

Comment: The problem is because you are using one mechanism to send completely different than to receive and so you are using the framework in a completely wrong manner, this is what we told you in the jpos list and you chose completely to ignore. if you ignore the answers of the people who work most with jpos in the world, how do you expect to learn something?

Comment: I do not ignore the answers from Jpos group, it is definitely the best place to find answers however you message bombing without expecting my response. It did not work with this `BaseChannel channel = new NACChannel(packager, tpduHeader);` so that is the reason why I used bytes. Let me get the mistake just using Channel. 
Also as you see incoming message do not have any kind of byte array.

Answer (score 0):

The is an error with the DocType line. I removed the line and then parsed the xml with xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string inputLine = "";
            while((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (inputLine.Contains("<!--"))
                     break;
            }
            if (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);

                var results = doc.Descendants("isopackager").Select(x => new
                {
                    isofields = x.Elements("isofield").Select(y => new
                    {
                        _class = (string)y.Attribute("name"),
                        name = (string)y.Attribute("class"),
                        length = (int)y.Attribute("length"),
                        id = (int)y.Attribute("id")
                    }).ToList(),
                    isofieldpackager = x.Elements("isofieldpackager").Select(y => new
                    {
                        _class = (string)y.Attribute("name"),
                        name = (string)y.Attribute("class"),
                        length = (int)y.Attribute("length"),
                        id = (int)y.Attribute("id"),
                        packager = (string)y.Attribute("packager"),
                        isofields = x.Elements("isofield").Select(z => new
                        {
                            _class = (string)z.Attribute("name"),
                            name = (string)z.Attribute("class"),
                            length = (int)z.Attribute("length"),
                            id = (int)z.Attribute("id")
                        }).ToList()
                    }).FirstOrDefault(),
                }).FirstOrDefault();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @jdweng, there is two bytes header incoming, I need to block it, do you have some recommendations.

Comment: I updated the code to read past the error using streamreader.  I've done this type hack before, but some people do not like this solution.  Some xml files do not have returns on every line so the fix will not work.  But since your xml does have returns the fix will work.  I've seen less than 1% of xml files not have returns.